# EF4 CTP5 Code First approach ignores Table attributes

Tags: entity-framework-4, code-first

I'm using EF4 CTP5 code first approach but am having trouble getting it to work. I have a class called "Company" and a database table called "CompanyTable". I want to map the Company class to the CompanyTable table, so have code like this:

```
[Table(Name = "CompanyTable")]
    public class Company
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Name = "CompanyIdNumber", DbType = "int")]
        public int CompanyNumber { get; set; }

        [Column(Name = "CompanyName", DbType = "varchar")]
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    }
```

I then call it like so:

```
var db = new Users();
            var companies = (from c in db.Companies
                            select c).ToList();
```

However it errors out:

**Invalid object name 'dbo.Companies'.**

It's obviously not respecting the Table attribute on the class, even though it says [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2010/12/06/ef-feature-ctp5-code-first-walkthrough.aspx) that Table attribute is supported. Also it's pluralizing the name it's searching for (Companies instead of Company.) How do I map the class to the table name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to add a reference to the ctp5 dll to my schemas project, it was using System.Data.Linq.Mapping instead.

Answer (score 1):

on you class that inherits from DbContext, override the OnModelCreating method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Company>().ToTable("dbo.CompanyTable");
        }
```