# Entity Framework Class Naming Conventions v Old School Database Naming Conventions

Tags: frameworks, ado.net, entity

I am looking at using some kind of Data Generation technology for my next project and was curious about the ADO.NET Entity Framework using Visual Studio 2010.  I am new to the entity framework so please be gentle.

My preference for class naming has always been camel case.  For example CustomerSite.
My preference for database naming has always been lowercase with underscores.  For example customer_site.  This seems to be the norm over the last decade where I have worked with database administrators from many companies which is why I adopted this technique.

Using the entity framework to generate my classes, it always uses the table name, so my class name becomes customer_site.  Which I hate.

I am mid-coding through a prototype, where the database has many tables (say around 40).  At present, I have been working on my own Data Model, but I am sick of hand-coding fields and properties.  It is a VB.NET WinForm application with standard CRUD for entities with vareious bells and whistles on top.

Is it possible to make the entity framework class generator use the naming convention of what I want or not?  Or do I need to change my database naming conventions?  Or just go with what the entity framework class generator gives me - customer_site as class name.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Andez

Comment: Are you working with EF code-first, or model-first?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493819/ef4-ctp5-code-first-approach-ignores-table-attributes), you can set up mapping between your entities and your tables which enables you to have different table and class names. You can do this by overriding `DbContext.OnModelCreating`, or by using the `TableAttribute`.

I'd say if you're comfortable doing it you should stick to different naming conventions for your tables and entities.

Comment: OK thanks for that Steve.  Out of curiosity, if I created the 40+ tables first, i.e. customer_site, I guess there would be not easy way to change the class names to suit other than to edit them in the designer?  Would I be right in thinking?

Comment: I think that'd be right, yes. You also wouldn't be working 'code first' :)